# 'sol chi vuole si serbe fidele'

Tags: word-usage, translation

I am trying to understand this line, which is from Questa o Quella, an aria from Verdi's Rigoletto. If you are unaware, this is quite an old text.

> sol chi vuole si serbe fidele

I am struggling specifically with the role that the word 'si' plays here.

I have a couple of ideas, but I am afraid my level of Italian is quite low.

I am not sure if it means 'only those who wish should remain faithful **to each other**', 'only they who **themselves** wish to should remain faithful', or whether there is an archaic meaning of si that I am unaware of.

So could somebody please explain the role of si in this sentence.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the correct text is *si serbi fedele*, not *... serbe ...*.

Next, the meaning of the sentence is just (paraphrasing the OP's version): “only those who wish should remain faithful”. *Si serbi* is the subjunctive mood of *serbarsi*, which is the reflexive form of the verb [*serbare*](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/serbare) and means “remain” or “keep being”. So, in the whole aria the Duke describes his devotion to a kind of free love: he doesn't commit to any single woman and doesn't keep faithfulness in any esteem.